# How to embed IE (created using Watin) inside a WPF application

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, watin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I embeded IE in my wpf application and interact with it firing events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507184/can-i-embeded-ie-in-my-wpf-application-and-interact-with-it-firing-events)

I'm using Watin to open IE and make some work automaticcaly.

My question is: can I embeded this into a WPF application (so Watin will not open IE as standalone windows, but as part of my application)?