# Can I embeded IE in my wpf application and interact with it firing events

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer

Can I embeded IE in my wpf application and interact with it firing events? 
e.g. can I fill a form and press submit button programmatically?

Comment: I'm not sure how you do it in XAML, but you should be able to CoCreate the Webbrowser control COM object and then just manipulate it using the various COM interfaces it exposes to get the Document object and then traverse the DOM looking for your form elements.  The answer is `yes`, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable about WPF can yell you how.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link to the web browser control for WPF, this control was not part of the initial release of WPF, and was added in 3.5 SP1.  As long as you are targeting 3.5 SP1 you can use this control and interact with the content in it.  I have a WPF application that does use this control and we do a lot of JavaScript interactivity with the content from the browser by drawing on a WPF canvas and sending that information to the content API of the web browser control.

If you need an example I can look up some code samples from the application and send them your way.